# Uninstall python package installed with `pip install --egg`

Tags: python, pip, scons, package-managers

I installed SCons with `pip install --egg scons`. Now I want to uninstall it, but pip tells me that there is no package named scons, even though I can still call it from the command line. What is the proper way to remove it?

Comment: which version of scons?

Comment: Which version of pip?

Comment: Are you sure you are picking up scons from your virtualenv? I just tested locally and no issue.. (assuming you're on a unix'y os try "which scons")

Answer (score 1):

It happened to me as well. I think you tried `pip install --egg scons` since the normal way of installing gives you an error as discussed [here](http://scons.1086193.n5.nabble.com/Issue-2769-New-pip-install-fails-option-signle-version-externally-managed-not-recognized-td1537.html).

Now to your problem, `pip install --egg <package>` spreads across installed files into the virtual-environment directory. I found this by running `find -name *scons*` in my virtual-environment directory:

```
./lib/scons-2.4.1
 <lot of files>
./lib/scons-2.4.1/SCons/compat/_scons_io.pyc
./lib/python2.7/site-packages/scipy/lib/lapack/scons_support.py
./lib/python2.7/site-packages/scipy/lib/lapack/scons_support.pyc
./lib/python2.7/site-packages/scipy/lib/blas/scons_support.py
./lib/python2.7/site-packages/scipy/lib/blas/scons_support.pyc
./man/man1/scons-time.1
./man/man1/sconsign.1
./man/man1/scons.1
./bin/sconsign-2.4.1
./bin/scons-time-2.4.1
./bin/scons-2.4.1
./bin/sconsign
./bin/scons-time
./bin/scons
```

Deleting `<virtualenv>/lib/scons-2.4.1`, `<virtualenv>/man/man1/scons*` and `<virtualenv>/bin/scons*` should remove the installation.

Comment: Same question. What version of pip are you using?

Comment: I am using `pip 7.1.2`

Comment: Just tried: pip install --egg scons, pip uninstall scons, and find. Find comes up blank. no scons named files in my virtualenv with pip 7.1.2. Strange.  see here: https://pastebin.mozilla.org/8857250